# _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '['

Tags: python, pickle

I'm currently programming a simple pygame platformer, and I'm using Python's `pickle` module. For each of the levels I have different files. I'm trying to store them in the `world_data` variable with this code:

```
if path.exists(f'level{level}_data'):
    pickle_in = open(f'level{level}_data', 'rb')
    world_data = pickle.load(pickle_in)
world = World(world_data)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
line 333, in <module>
    world_data = pickle.load(pickle_in)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '['.
```

I searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

This is what one of my level files look like:

```
[
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

Do I got something wrong with my file? Or something wrong with my code? Please help me

Comment: share the code where you do `pickle.dump`

Comment: `pickle` is a compressed binary format.  You can only `load` something that has been `pickle.dump`ed.  If your level file looks exactly like your example, that is not a valid pickle file.  (Though you could probably load it with `json.load` or `ast.literal_eval`.)

Comment: I don't exactly do a pickle.dump, so I will try to change my level's format and then try to run it again. But in which format does it need to be?

Comment: You can use your level-files as they are. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)-Docs, pickle is for serilization. You can't use it to read in your level-files.

To read you level-files you can use something like proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/8106583) by Roger Pate.

> ```
> >>> import ast
> >>> x = '[ "A","B","C" , " D"]'
> >>> x = ast.literal_eval(x)
> >>> x
> ['A', 'B', 'C', ' D']
> ```

in your code it would look like

```
if path.exists(f'level{level}_data'):
    ast_in = open(f'level{level}_data', 'rb')
    world_data = ast.literal_eval(ast_in.read())
world = World(world_data)
```

Comment: No problem :) Please accept the answer as correkt if it worked for you. Have a nice day.

Comment: That gives me this error: `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_io.BufferedReader name='level1_data'>` But `json.load()` worked fine. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot a `.read()`. Should be working now. Try again :D